# How to add meta description in Wordpress bridge theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress theme. When I add meta description in header.php by wordpress dashboard editor then its not updated always showed "**The connection was reset**"

**meta syntex**

```
<meta name="description" content="......................................" />
```

Comment: Hi friends, Its solved

Answer (score 1):

Add meta description like the following in your functions.php

```
function hook_meta() {
    ?>
        <meta name="description" content="......................................" />
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hook_meta');
```